# how to flatten control/escape characters for clean file redirection in BASH linux

Tags: bash, terminal, escaping, ansi-colors

I'm looking for something that can remove control characters from an echo output and convert it to a string without control characters, while still looking exactly the same as in a bash terminal.

This is an example of the problem:

```
root@spt01:~/scripts/ms-ad# echo -e "123456\rA"
A23456
root@spt01:~/scripts/ms-ad# echo -e "123456\rA" > /tmp/test ; more /tmp/test
123456
```

so /tmp/test should contain A23456 , not 123456\r

I tried using sponge, tee, ansi2txt, all without success.
Some do seem to work with \b backspace codes, but the \r carriage return seems an issue.

Also, I know you can use less -r to view the file correctly, but then the control chars are not removed from the file.

any ideas??? sure there must be a magical tool out there.

thanks! D

Comment: Do you really want in the resulting string the 'A' shift to the beginning? You see it **displayed** as the first character of the line, because the terminal program is putting it there (due to the \r in front), but in the string, it still occurs at the end.

Comment: this is just an example to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: It is still unclear, why in the example you want to have the character at the end of the string moved to its start in the desired result, because the string is 123456\r**A** and you want to get **A**123456 and not, as one would thingk 123456**A**.

Comment: Again, this is just to demonstrate the \r behaviour. If I had a script that would output some sort of progress, showing the current processed line, without using new lines, I would also use echo -n -e "$i\r  ". When redirecting the output to a file, this would look different from what you see in the terminal, because the control chars are included in the file as well. I only want the control chars have rendered on the screen.

Comment: I believe the processing of the display depends on the terminal program -- not on the shell itself.   So if you do `echo -e "1\b2"`, then the shell actually outputs `1`, `\b` and `2` to the terminal program which then process this and outputs `2`...   So you're looking for something that simulates the behavior of the terminal.   I'm unfortunately not aware of anything like that.   Shouldn't be to hard to write though...

Comment: I deleted my answer. OP wants to capture output as if control characters including "\r" had made an effect, but without actually including them. I don't know of a tool that can do that.

Comment: use printf instead echo

Comment: printf gives the same result unfortunatly

Comment: `printf "123456\rA" > /tmp/test` returns A for me (that means \r is resolved)

Comment: it does show "A", but not "A23456", like echo -e "123456\rA" does

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEP5k.png

Comment: hi alecxs ... that is correct behaviour. But look into that file with a text editor (vi) ... you'll see it different.